# TS type guards with complex type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have encountered an interesting behaviour of TS type guards and would like to ask you whether I just have to accept it or whether I am doing something wrong. I put together minimal example (well, close to minimal).

```
enum LegType {
  LegA = 'LegA',
  LegB = 'LegB',
}

interface LegA {
  type: LegType.LegA
  foo: string
}

interface LegB {
  type: LegType.LegB
  bar: string
}

type Leg = LegA | LegB

enum PlanType {
  T = 'T',
  C = 'C',
}

interface TPlan {
  type: PlanType.T
  legs: LegA[]
}

interface CPlan {
  type: PlanType.C
  legs: (LegA | LegB)[]
}

type Plan = TPlan | CPlan

const isLegA = (o: Leg): o is LegA => o.type === LegType.LegA

const getFoo = (plan: Plan): string | undefined => {
  // const legs: Leg[] = plan.legs // With this line the code builds with no errors.
  const legs = plan.legs // With this line the code contains error, the type of `legs` is resolved as: LegA[] | (LegA | LegB)[]
  const someLegA = legs.find(isLegA)
  return someLegA?.foo // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'LegA | LegB'.
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/LAKApgdgrgtgBAGTAcwCoE8AOY4G9RyIoCCcAvHAORLLGUA0BRyAQuVTSw6AL6igBLCABcwAJwBmAQwDGOGqXwhCwrGABczDNgB0CphID2hzQGdhYocl78QQ0ZNnyUbJSrWaa2sHpdMARlJiZhZWNiCgqtjM7ApwAD7MLLaQsHAACgA2UhDeeEyoUgAeAuyUhSXcynAAwoYw-qUUlHUNAlV8EXYi4tJycBUCWTn51VEaGdm5ajqDTJkopp4kANoAuuGCPY79rY3DEKPu2JoH3jp7AvOLmgAUcYmcAJTrmyDjkyMUgwcJtfX7Ka2GSGCDmOACUxxCi3EzMJ6aQwQ0zMUhkAB8cEMOg%20ZDxWhm%20i6ILBwjgyDAwgAYsZ2LdMFNTlMEXBzJYIMg-lAIAATMASIRgHnkTFuOAAenFcBJ4IWyCWzHW7AZOR0cpRkrgAHUBMIABZwfWQuCZQWGvU4EF8uD%20KACTI8lEAd11BogSPEYkMYlMOiYMrJ6uVUzViwlUp1%20vNxtNEBw%20sthmtJOEUiEKM93vo5vjaixEjgAAN1YXkXAxGBTIZMgA3IVwKQKhRKxL3Eh-Z6vaoB1n1MDQk2LHQC3m3SEKJ5MCvCKBiQ5VmD9kgAfmHtM16S92DEqioRkMlDgPMMlbg7rJYBK4NBhrz1HbjxclD9IE6QA)

Why is adding `:Leg[]` necessary? Is it possible to rewrite  the code so that TS understands itself what the correct type is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuck, I see what's happening and I think the only reasonable answer here is to do what you did: annotate `legs` as `Leg[]`.

So, the [library type signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.2/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31-L32)  for `Array`'s `find()` method is [overloaded](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and the overload that accepts a [user-defined type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) callback and returns a narrowed element type is [generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

> ```
> find<S extends T>(
>     predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any
>   ): S | undefined;
>
> find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T | undefined;
> ```

When you don't annotate `legs`, it gets the [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) `Array<Leg> | Array<LegA>`.  This type is considered compatible with `Array<Leg>` but it won't treat it as such automatically (which is probably good.  An `Array<LegA>` should not let you `push()` a `LegB` onto it, but an `Array<Leg>` should).

That means that the type of `legs.find` is itself a *union* of functions whose signatures are not identical:

```
type LegsFind = {
  <S extends LegA>(p: (this: void, v: LegA, i: number, o: LegA[]) => v is S, t?: any): S | undefined;
  (p: (v: LegA, i: number, o: LegA[]) => unknown, t?: any): LegA | undefined;
} | {
  <S extends Leg>(p: (this: void, v: Leg, i: number, o: Leg[]) => v is S, t?: any): S | undefined;
  (p: (v: Leg, i: number, o: Leg[]) => unknown, t?: any): Leg | undefined;
};
```

Prior to TypeScript 3.3 the compiler would just give up and tell you it doesn't know how to call a union of functions like this.  And someone would tell you to change `Array<X> | Array<Y>` to `Array<X | Y>` if you're calling non-mutating methods like `find()`, and you'd use `Leg[]` and move on.

---

TypeScript 3.3 introduced [improved behavior for calling union types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  There are cases when the compiler can take a union of functions and represent it as a single function which takes an [intersection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of the parameters from each member of the union.  You can read more about it in the relevant pull request, [microsoft/TypeScript#29011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011).

But, [there are cases when it can't do this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats): specifically if multiple legs of the union are overloaded or generic functions.  Unfortunately for `find()`, that's the case you're in.  It looks like the compiler *tries* to figure out a way to make this callable, but it gives up on the generic signatures corresponding to user-defined-type-guard narrowing and ends up with just the "regular" one, probably because they are compatible with each other:

```
type LegsFind33 = (p: (v: LegA, i: number, o: Leg[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any) => Leg | undefined;
```

So you call it successfully, no narrowing takes place, and you run into the problem here.  The issue of calling unions of functions is not completely solved; its GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#7294](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294) is closed and labeled "Revisit".

So until that is revisited, the advice here is *still* to treat `Array<X> | Array<Y>` like`Array<X | Y>` if you're calling non-mutating methods like `find()`... use `Leg[]` and move on.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for great clarification.